# How do I add Lists in Modelio class diagram?

Tags: oop, uml, project, modelio

Using more strict modeling tools (unlike just paint editors) makes you to remember at least basic `UML specification`.

For example, in the case of `modelio`, you have to seperately add to the diagram any specific data type which is further used within the class attribute's declaration.

But how do I set a `List` of objects as a data type? I'm currently using `Miltiplicity min` and `Multiplicity max` parameters to set the link multiplicity proprties.

[image]

I guess these params are more likely for declaring simple arrays.

[image]

Comment: See also `collection type` in https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html#multiplicity-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UML, you can specify the multiplicities of a property in order to specify that is a collection. But at the implementation/code level, several collection implementation may correspond to a specific UML model.

That's why code generator can, usually,  be customized to targed one specific code implementation. In Modelio, this customization can be done thanks to the Java tab as depicted below. By default, a Property with "*" as multiplicity max will be generated as an Array. To taget another type of Collection you have to play with the "Collection to use" enumeration and set the one you want.

[image]

Hoping it helps.
EBR